# Finding the derivative of $f(x) = 2x^2 + x - 3$ at $x = 4$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am learning about derivatives and differentiating and I came across this;

$f(x) = 2x^2 + x - 3$ at $x = 4$

This is as far as I get;
$$\frac{2(x + h)^2 + (x + h) - 3 - (2x^2 - x + 3)}{ h }$$

$$\frac{2(x^2 + 2xh + h^2) + x + h - 3 - (2x^2 - x + 3)}{ h }$$

$$\frac{2x^2 + 4xh + 2h^2 + x + h - 3 - 2x^2 - x + 3}{ h }$$

The answer I get is $$\frac{4xh + 2h^2 + h}{ h }$$

How can I reduce that further, and am I doing this correctly? Because the answers they show are
$f'(x) = 4x+3$
$f '(x) = 2x-3$
$f '(x) = 4x+1$
$f '(x) = 4x-a$

I think I am doing something wrong or not reducing it correctly. I would really appreciate some guidance asap.

Thanks!

Comment: You're doing great.  Starting where you left off, try dividing the top and bottom of your fraction both by $h$.

Comment: Typo in the 2nd line : it should be $$2x^2-x-3$$

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. When I do that I am still left with 4xh + 2h^2 though?

Comment: Well, once you don't have any h's in the denominator, you can apply the limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See what happens when you cancel the $h$ in the numerator and the denominator, and then send $h$ to zero.  That should get you one of the choices listed.  Good luck!

Comment: I really appreciate your help thank you, but I am still confused :( If I cancel the h in the numerator and the denominator I would still be left with 4xh + 2h^2? Or is that not what you meant? I have been working on these for hours and my brain is starting to melt haha

Comment: @user3247128 By cancel, he means dividing both the numerator and denominator by $h$!